# How to replace with for loop statement by matching different files in shell/bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

With my shell script i'm trying to match 2 different files and replace the occurencies in File1 with the lines of File2:

```
File1 occurency 1 <-- File2 row 1
File1 occurency 2 <-- File2 row 2
File1 occurency 3 <-- File2 row 3
...
```

The number of rows in File 2 is equal to occurencies in File 1 because initialy they were taken from File 1

File1 - is a Json file

```
...
"@type" : "Review",
"@id":"https://google.com/social/profile/xxxxxxx.jpg"
"datePublished" : "Tue Sep 18 16:32:53 CEST 2012",

"@type" : "Review",
"@id":"https://google.com/social/profile/xxxxxxx.jpg"
"datePublished" : "Tue Sep 18 16:32:53 CEST 2012",
 ...
```

File2 - is a formated "json like" file

```
"profilePhoto":"https://someurl.ltd/aaaa_90.jpg"
"profilePhoto":"https://someurl.ltd/bbbb_90.jpg"
"profilePhoto":"https://someurl.ltd/cccc_90.jpg"
 ....
```

Actually the part of script that have to make this job looks like

```
IFS=$'\n'
set -f
for i in $(cat < File2.txt); do

sed -i "s|.*social.*|$i|g" File1.json

done
```

This script replace all occurencies in File1 with the first line of File2, so on second loop there is no more matching to find.
output example

```
...
"@type" : "Review",
"profilePhoto":"https://someurl.ltd/cccc_90.jpg"
"datePublished" : "Tue Sep 18 16:32:53 CEST 2012",

"@type" : "Review",
"profilePhoto":"https://someurl.ltd/cccc_90.jpg"
"datePublished" : "Tue Sep 18 16:32:53 CEST 2012",
 ...
```

I need instead the output like this

```
...
"@type" : "Review",
*"profilePhoto":"https://someurl.ltd/**aaaa**_90.jpg"*
"datePublished" : "Tue Sep 18 16:32:53 CEST 2012",

"@type" : "Review",
*"profilePhoto":"https://someurl.ltd/**bbbb**_90.jpg"*
"datePublished" : "Tue Sep 18 16:32:53 CEST 2012",
 ...
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `for i in $(cat < File2.txt); do ... done` is better written `while IFS= read -r i; do ... done < File2.txt`

Comment: Ewww, unless you are actually expecting the field splitting and have multiple words on each line.

Comment: How many lines are in File2?

Comment: Hi Denis
the File2 is a dynamic file. the number of lines is changing every time, but it is always the same as on File1

Comment: Based on your examples, assuming a one-to-one correspondence, File1 has four times as many lines as File2. How many lines do these files have? Tens? Hundreds? Thousands?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

After reviewing what your desired output a lot closer i came up with this

```
for i in $(sed 's/^/*/;s|ltd/|&**|;s|_|**&|;s/$/*/' File2.txt); do awk -i inplace -v i="$i" 'NR==1,/.*social.*/{sub(/.*social.*/, i)} 1' File1.json; done
```

Once you limit the substitution in File1.json to only the first occurrence you can let the loop work for you.

To break it down

```
# Instead of cat file I tackled substitution for each line in File2.txt as $i
for i in $(sed 's/^/*/;s|ltd/|&**|;s|_|**&|;s/$/*/' File2.txt); do

    # Here awk sub only first occurrence to not overwrite whole file
    # Second loop will handle the next occurrence with second line from File2.txt  
    # And third ect.. ect..
    awk -i inplace -v i="$i" 'NR==1,/.*social.*/{sub(/.*social.*/, i)} 1' File1.json
done
```

Everything below is if your version of awk does not support -i inplace then you will have to do this

```
awk -v i="$i" 'NR==1,/.*social.*/{sub(/.*social.*/, i)} 1 { rec = rec $0 RS } END { close(FILENAME); printf "%s", rec > FILENAME }' File1.json
```

So the whole thing will look like

```
 # Instead of cat file I tackled substitution for each line in File2.txt as $i
for i in $(sed 's/^/*/;s|ltd/|&**|;s|_|**&|;s/$/*/' File2.txt); do

    # Here awk sub only first occurrence to not overwrite whole file
    # Second loop will handle the next occurrence with second line from File2.txt  
    # And third ect.. ect..
    awk -v i="$i" 'NR==1,/.*social.*/{sub(/.*social.*/, i)} 1 { rec = rec $0 RS } END { close(FILENAME); printf "%s", rec > FILENAME }' File1.json
done
```

Finally if you neither of the above awk commands work you can result to temp files.

```
awk -v i="$i" 'NR==1,/.*social.*/{sub(/.*social.*/, i)} 1' File1.json > tmpfile && mv tmpfile File1.json
```

so the whole thing will look like this

```
for i in `cat File2.txt`; do

 awk -v i="$i" 'NR==1,/.*social.*/{sub(/.*social.*/, i)} 1' File1.json > tmpfile && mv tmpfile File1.json

done
```

Comment: Adding asterisks to the right hand side of the `s` command is going to result in literal asterisks in the output which I doubt is what the OP wants. I think he used the asterisks for emphasis.

Comment: Thanks Goose,
but your solution doesn't works. On first loop It is still override all occorences, so at the second loop it can't find more ".*social.*"


i found this kind of command, i'm trying to fit it on my code

`sed -i "0,/name:/{s/name:.*/name: ${NEW_VALUE}/}" ./myFile`

Comment: @AlexandrMisiyuk I updated my code i think this is more like what you are looking for. I learned my lesson ill pay more attention to reading desired outputs.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You're absolutely right that's what i get for skimming. That was too easy i should have known

Comment: What version of awk are you using? I don't know of one that supports `-i`.for in place  file modification. That option has a [different function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options) in GNU awk at least.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson What other way is there to do it? That is GNU awk. Does the code not work for you?  The code works for me im using awk version GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2) Thats the only way i know how to use inplace or substitution in awk

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I edited the code again incase you dont have a version of GNU awk that works like mine the extra code i put in does the same thing just a little longer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see that it's a loadable extension. I was not aware of that feature.

Comment: @AlexandrMisiyuk i have added one more bit to the bottom of my answer to solve your awk problem. It would be nice if this solves your problem to check the question as answered rather than posting your own answer

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/xxxxxxx\.jpg/R file2' -e '//d' file1
```

This replaces each line the contains `xxxxxxx.jpg` by a line from file2.

Comment: Note: This is a replacement for the complete for-loop.

Comment: i try to execute it, the result is that it remove whole line in File1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys!

After checking the suggestion of @goose i just make a little change
and the final solution that works for that issue is

```
for i in `cat jsonlike.txt`; do

awk -v i="$i" 'NR==1,/.*social.*/{sub(/.*social.*/, i)} 1 { rec = rec $0 RS } END { close(FILENAME); printf "%s", rec > FILENAME }' File1.json

done
```

i know that it can be done withe the while loop too, but it's ok even like this for me.
thank you

Comment: Damn it!
for some kind of strange mistake it doesn't works more...
the "AWK" command doesn't execute if i launch a bash script..
i have linux 6 with awk 3 that doesn't support replace in place.